# Pillow does not seem to work inside a function, but works fine on interpreter

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The function below, part of a bigger class works fine on all the images except this one -> http://www.worldbank.org/content/dam/wbr/About/Pres/jyk-hs-offical.png

```
def _fetch_image_size(self, image_url):
    size = None
    if '.svg' not in image_url:
        response = requests.get(image_url, headers=self._headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            response.raw.decode_content = True
            try:
                image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
                size = image.size
            except (IOError, OSError) as error:
                print error
                print image_url
        response.close()
    return size
```

when the above function is called as part of the class object, it raises me this error.

> cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x1062e1b30>

however on the command line interpreter, when i do this

```
import io, requests
from PIL import Image

response = requests.get('http://www.worldbank.org/content/dam/wbr/About/Pres/jyk-hs-offical.png')
response.raw.decode_content = True
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
print image.size
```

the output is,

```
(220, 220)
```

i am unable to figure out why is it happening?

Comment: The method works for me if I change the `requests.get(image_url, headers=self._headers)` to be just `response = requests.get(image_url)` like the way it was called in the python shell.

Comment: nopse, doesn't make a difference for me. still getting ```cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x112997830>```

Answer (score 0):

sorry to bother you all. it appears that i need to sanitize my url in my class and look for blankspaces. Nothing wrong with PIL here.

here is how i pin pointed the faulty code, if anybody is interested.

thankyou for your response. I have diagnosed the problem. pasting the problematic code from my class here.

```
def _extract_image_urls(self, soup):
    """
    extracts all the <img src=''> tags

    Args:
        soup (obj): the BeautifulSoup object

    Returns:
        url (str): string for url
    """
    for img in soup.findAll("img", src=True):
        yield urlparse.urljoin(self._url, img["src"])
```

```

this above code gets me all the urls i need to pass onto my `_fetch_image_size()` function.

i modified my `_fetch_image_size` function to have this

```
.....
response = requests.get(image_url, headers=self._headers)
print 'Request URL: {url}'.format(url=image_url)
print 'Response URL: {url}'.format(url=response.url)
.....
```

and here is the response.

> s = LinkScraper('http://www.worldbank.org/en/about/president/about-the-office/bio')
>   Request URL: http://www.worldbank.org/content/dam/wbr/img/mobile-menu-lines.png
>   Response URL: http://www.worldbank.org/content/dam/wbr/img/mobile-menu-lines.png
>
> Request URL: http://www.worldbank.org/etc/designs/wbr/clientlibs/img/icon-search-black.png
>   Response URL: http://www.worldbank.org/etc/designs/wbr/clientlibs/img/icon-search-black.png
>
> Request URL: http://www.worldbank.org/content/dam/wbr/About/Pres/jyk-hs-offical.png
>   Response URL: http://www.worldbank.org/404_response.htm
>   Error: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x112414830>

the response that is being passed into the PIL.Image function is an http response and not an image at all!. Nothing wrong with PIL here. I need to sanitize my urls to look for blank spaces here maybe.

thank you @martineau for taking the time. Much appreciated.

//mouse.